# VS2010 + NUnit failing to load assemblies?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, visual-studio-2010, nunit, c#-4.0

Im using VS2010, C# 4.0, NHibernate and NUnit in a project Im working on.. In doing database tests I've come across a wierd problem.. When I run my tests, nunit-agent.exe crashes for no apparent reason.. I've since then discovered that when i debug my tests, I get the following exception in the TestFixtureSetup method:

> TypeInitializationException: The type
>   initializer for
>   'NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactory'
>   threw an exception.
>   Could not load file or assembly
>   'Castle.DynamicProxy2,
>   Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does
>   not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)":"Castle.DynamicProxy2,
>   Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc

Now, it seems to me that what it's looking for is identical to the one it found?

I've doublechecked and the assembly is referenced in the test project.. I have also tried readding the reference, but to no avail.. Any ideas?

**UPDATE2:** I tried changing the target framework to .net 3.5 of all my projects and now all tests fail with the error above..

**UPDATE:** Some tests works, others dont.. I have a customer class:

```
public class Customer : IEntity<string>
{
  private readonly string id;
  public virtual string Id
  {
    get { return id; }
  }

  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

Where the tests runs perfectly fine.. However tests for my product class:

```
public class Product : IEntity<string>
{
  private readonly string id;

  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }

  public virtual string Id 
  {
    get { return Id; }
  }
}
```

Does not work (I get the exception from before).. And the funny thing is that tests for both classes uses the exact same base class that contains all the database access code..

Comment: what .net version are your projects? and what .net version is DP2?

Comment: My projects are C# 4.0 and I downloaded the lastest DynamicProxy dll from Castle Project.. As far as I can tell, it is for .net 2.0 runtime..

Comment: We've experienced some vague problems as well when a .NET4.0 project (really, .NET framework version) references assemblies that are targetting an older version of the framework.
We haven't invested much time in searching for a solution; we just decided to not use .NET 4.0 at the moment yet.  (Which won't prevent us from using C#4.0 though).

Comment: Yeah as I pointed out in update2 above, I tried targeting .net 3.5 instead, however, now I still get the same exception (only for all tests this time)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.. It seems Nhibernate was looking for DynamicProxy 2.1.0 while I had referenced 2.1.1..